# Elasticsearch: What operation can only be executed on master node?

Tags: elasticsearch

It seems that for every node in the cluster, you can curl port 9200 to call most of the REST api. I wonder, is there any operation (or an extensive list of such operations) that can only be executed by accessing the master node?

Answer (score 1):

There is no operation that can only be asked to the master node, becaue when you ask something to any node it will route it to the correct node. So if you ask something that should be traited by the master node to a non master node, it will be be routed by the non master node to the master node. This feature allow Elasticsearch to elect a new master node without breaking any code!